# Accessing dynamic variable name - external contract

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing, state-variable

Contract A wants to call an external contract B/C/D/E/F but the variable name is different within each contract B/C/D/E/F, and contract A does not know the variable name for B/C/D/E/F at the start.

```
---Contract A---
function callExternal(address _externalContract, string _variableName) public {
  interface(_externalContract)._variableName
}


---Contract B---
uint256 public variableName;


---Contract C---
uint256 public aDifferentVariableName;
```

One route is to go through storage slots, but that assumes that each contract will have the same ordering of storage slots.  How can I look up specifically the passed in string on another contract.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution for this would be to create a getter function in the other contracts, that share the same name. Then you can just call that function from contract A to get the variable.

```
interface Interface {
  function getVariable() external view returns (uint256);
}

contract A {
  function callExternal(address externalContract) public view returns (uint256) {
    return Interface(externalContract).getVariable();
  }
}

contract B is Interface {
  uint256 public foo;
    
  function getVariable() override view external returns (uint256) {
    return foo;
  }
}


contract C is Interface {
  uint256 public bar;
    
  function getVariable() override view external returns (uint256) {
    return bar;
  }
}
```

Now you can simply call `A.callExternal(<address of B/C>);` to get the value.

Alternatively, you can use `staticcall` to get the variables from a string name, since public variables are essentially getters on their own. This requires a bit more extra code though, to get the function selector from a string:

```
contract A {
  function callExternal(address externalContract, string calldata variableName) public view returns (uint256) {
    (bool success, bytes memory data) = externalContract.staticcall(
      abi.encodeWithSelector(
        bytes4(
          keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(
              variableName,
              "()"
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
    
    if (success) {
      return abi.decode(data, (uint256));
    }
  }
}
```

Now calling `A.callExternal(<address of B>, "foo")` will return `foo` from contract B. Note that the variables must be public for this to work.

Comment: The second solution is the most applicable as my question wasn't clear - the contracts that I wish to get the value from have already been deployed, and are not in my control.

In terms of the static call is there a reason why you wrap it inside of:

     `abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(`

instead of just wrapping it inside of  `abi.encodeWithSelector` for example

Comment: `bytes4(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(...)))` is necessary to concatenate the strings (basically `variableName + "()"`). Alternatively you could just use `abi.encodeWithSignature(variableName)` and specify `foo()` or `bar()` as name.

Comment: Perfect! thanks so much for the assistance

Out of curiosity if I was to call a function instead of a variable.  I would replace `variableName,"()"` with `functionName,"(_param1, _param2)"`?

Comment: For functions with parameters you can use `abi.encodeWithSignature("<signature>", param1, param2)`, where the signature is something like `function(type1,type2)`. 
See the documentation: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.1/units-and-global-variables.html#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions